# Cannot connect to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

I have just installed the latest version of ubuntu and I cannot connect to WiFi.  I have not used ubuntu before so I'm struggling to get it to work. I have an Acer aspire laptop that was using windows 10. The wireless adapter was working OK with windows 10, but with ubuntu when I click on the network section it only comes up with a wired connection. It does not find the WiFi. I do not have a cable so I cannot use the wired connection to get it started. 
Can anyone help?

Thanks

Output of `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f1  no wireless extensions.



david@david-Aspire-E5-571:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net A3
grep: A3: No such file or directory
david@david-Aspire-E5-571:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)



david@david-Aspire-E5-571:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
david@david-Aspire-E5-571:~$
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What's the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you also edit the question to include the output of `lspci -knn` and `rfkill list all`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

- Open 'Network Settings'
- Choose 'Connect to a Hidden Network'
- For Network Name, put the name of the network (in my case is was 'Gostinnyi dvir')
- For Network Security, choose 'WPA & WPA2 Personal'
- Then just type in password.